# Difficulty exiting "user input" method called in main Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am trying to bring in some numerical values by way of Scanner(System.in). I am calling a class with my method from main and having a difficult time exiting the method, my questions are looping.

I am sure this is a simple issue but I am having a heck of a time finding a solution.

Here is the method:

```
public static Object userInput(double nutWidth, double lastFretWidth, double scaleLength, int numFrets) {

    boolean dataCheck = true;
    try {
        while (dataCheck == true) {
            System.out.println("What is the width at the nut?");
            NutWidth = key.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("What is the width at the last fret?");
            LastFretWidth = key.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("What is the scale length?");
            ScaleLength = key.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("How many frets will your guitar have?");
            NumFrets = key.nextInt();
            dataCheck = false;
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a integer.");
        key.nextInt();
    }

    return userInput(NutWidth, LastFretWidth, ScaleLength, NumFrets);
}
```

Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FingerBoard.userInput(0, 0, 0, 0);
    FingerBoard.UserData();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated-Mike

Comment: You have [`infinite recursion`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion) as your return statement keeps calling `userInput` and there is no base case

Comment: Thank you. So I gather the while statement is pointless and the issue is that the values need to be passed as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have written an infinite recursion. The line

```
return userInput(NutWidth, LastFretWidth, ScaleLength, NumFrets);
```

will call the same method again after finishing the previous method. It looks to me like you want to store the values in a data structure and return that, which would require calling a constructor something like this:

```
return new UserInput(NutWidth, LastFretWidth, ScaleLength, NumFrets);
```

You would have to write the data structure UserInput yourself. If you haven't gotten to writing classes and data structures yet, you probably want your variables to be static fields. If you are doing that, change the return type to be `void` and remove the return statement entirely.

Additional comments not related to your problem. You don't need the arguments to your method. They are never used. You probably also want to put the try/catch inside of the while loop. That way an invalid input will prompt for new input, rather than setting things to 0.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to explain.

Comment: Thanks very much, That worked very well. I got rid of the while loop, voided the method and added a enum class to return the information.